# Session Validation - Spring Security with Microservices

Tags: java, spring-security, redis, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-security

My current architecture for my web app has a gateway server that orchestrates a bunch of microservices, authorisation occurs at the gateway if a given principle is authenticated they can talk to some downstream services.

The downstream service gets hold of the required data to identify a given authenticated client. However spring securities default behaviour kicks in and throws the expected:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Given that I can use the session id and + XSRF token in any given Microservice to validate the user is authenticated and know which user is logged in (i'm currently using Http Basic).

**My question** is there a simpler / declarative approach that could be used in place of having to adding a filter to every Microservice to override spring securities default behaviour? (see my example Pseudo code)

*See the attached diagram:* Architecture.
[image]

Spring web security config for resource server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public SessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository() {
        return new MapSessionRepository();
    }


    @Bean
    HeaderHttpSessionStrategy sessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
              .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();


        final SessionRepositoryFilter<ExpiringSession> sessionRepositoryFilter = new SessionRepositoryFilter<ExpiringSession>(
                sessionRepository());
        sessionRepositoryFilter
                .setHttpSessionStrategy(new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy());

        http.addFilterBefore(sessionRepositoryFilter,
                ChannelProcessingFilter.class).csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

    }

    public SessionRepository<ExpiringSession> getSessionRepository(){
        return sessionRepository();
    }

}
```

Header values at the resource microservice:

```
KEY: cookie VALUE: XSRF-TOKEN=[token_value]; SESSION=[session_value]
KEY: x-requested-with VALUE: XMLHttpRequest
KEY: x-auth-token VALUE: a32302fd-589b-42e1-8b9d-1991a080e904
...
```

Planned approach **(Pseudo code)** attach a new filter to the spring securities filter chain that if given flags are true, allow access to secured endpoints.

```
**
 * A custom filter that can grant access to the current resource
 * if there is a valid XSRF-TOKEN and SESSION present in the shared
 * session cache.
 */
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends AnAppropriateFilterChainFilter {

    @Autowired
    SessionRepository sessionRepository;


    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {



        boolean csrfTokenExists = sessionRepository.findByCsrfTokenId(request);

        boolean sessionExists = sessionRepository.findBySessionId(request);

        if (csrfTokenExists && sessionExists) {
            // everything is okay
        } else {
            // invalidate the request as being authenticated
            throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("Invalid csrf + session pair");

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating my spring boot parent to `2.0.1 Release` and changing my spring cloud version to `Finchley` the issue was resolved by spring boot.

Note `session repository` and `HttpSessionStrategy` aren't required,

`HttpSessionStrategy` is now depreciated since spring session became spring session core.

Using the externalised config for `redis` and `spring boot`, all the dependant systems automatically use that cache for validating a valid session providing you have spring security on your class path.

Note if you are using the gateway pattern and `Zuul Proxy` ensure your proxy routes include the `sensitive-headers:` property in your app YML / properties, see examples below:

**Example auth + gateway using Springboot Configuration of a shared session cache.**

> Auth Gateway

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
  session:
    store-type: redis

server:
  port:   8080

zuul:
  routes:
    # local routes
    api:
      url: forward:/api
      path: /api/**
      sensitive-headers:
    # cloud-resource
    resource:
      url: http://localhost:9002
      path: /resource/**
      strip-prefix: false
      sensitive-headers:

proxy:
  auth:
    routes:
      resource: passthru
      ui: none
      api: passthru

security:
  sessions: ALWAYS
```

> Some Secured Resource Server

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
  session:
    store-type: redis
  security:
    enabled: false

server:
  port:  9002

security:
  # Never create a session, but if one exists use it
  sessions: NEVER
  # don't display the auth box
  basic:
    enabled: false

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```